# codeigniter kill session but use flashdata on redirect

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to write a function to kill my users session if their status in the database (for either company or user) is changed to false (this works fine).

Unfortunately, codeigniter does not let you set_flashdata easily after killing the session. I cannot work out how to re-initialise a new session, in order to store the flashdata for the redirection to the login page (and tell the user why they were booted out).

Searching on here and google hasn't really afforded me anything on recreating a session to use. I use CodeIgniter 3.0.3

Helper code:

```
function user_active($username)
{
    $CI =& get_instance();
    $CI->load->database();

    $CI->db->where('username', $username);
    $CI->db->from('users');
    $CI->db->join('company', 'company.orgID = users.orgID');

    $query = $CI->db->get();

    $result = $query->row_array();

    // check company active
    if($result['orgStatus'] != TRUE){
        $CI->session->sess_destroy();
        $CI->session->set_flashdata('flashError', 'Company currently disabled please contact accounts for reactivation');
        redirect(site_url(), 'refresh');
    }
    // check user active
    if($result['status'] != TRUE) {
        $CI->session->sess_destroy();
        $CI->session->set_flashdata('flashError', 'User not active, please contact your administrator');
        redirect(site_url(), 'refresh');
    }
}
```

Comment: You must validate with the database on every request. Means do this stuff on every request.

Comment: That has nothing to do with my question?

Comment: For me, no . For this kind of thing, What I does is, create a main controller that extends CI_Controller. Then every controller must extends that main controller you created. In the constructor of main controller, call your current function . For me, that is the best way and what I ever did.

Comment: Have you try using $CI->session->sess_regenerate(true) instead of $CI->session->sess_destroy ?

Comment: Please read my question again, it's to do with using flash data after killing a session... My helper works fine in terms of its actual function I just need a way to use flash data at redirect page

Comment: Yes, you kill a session but you did not generate a new one after that. So any session related function will not work as stated in the docs about sess_destroy `This must be the last session-related function that you call. All session data will be lost after you do that.`

Comment: Thanks otezz, I have tried it but it just half-breaks my site on redirect. I just need to either create a new session (cant seem to) or find another way to post the errors to my login page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the codeignitier's documentation,

> All session data (including flashdata and tempdata) will be destroyed
>   permanently and functions will be unusable during the same request
>   after you destroy the session.

So my suggestion to you to remove all the session data except the important ones.

```
$user_data = $this->session->userdata();
foreach ($user_data as $key => $value) {
    if ($key!='__ci_last_regenerate' && $key != '__ci_vars')
       $this->session->unset_userdata($key);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't destroy the session. Use `unset_userdata()` to unset your unwanted session. `$this->session->unset_userdata('session_name');` It may solve your problem. For additional server request you can use `$this->session->keep_flashdata('session_name')`